# "Qt 3.x not found please set QT_INCLUDE, QT_LIB, MOC by hand" on my ubuntu14.04

Tags: qt, configure, github, qt3

I'm trying to install gmapping package from github https://github.com/nii2121/gmapping/blob/master/docs/Instructions.txt
and after I run

```
./configure
```

It turns out to be

```
No 'CXX' environment variable found, using g++.
No 'CC' environment variable found, using gcc.
Using C++ compiler: g++
Using C compiler: gcc
Checking for Qt 3.x ... 

*** Qt 3.x not found please set QT_INCLUDE, QT_LIB, MOC by hand
```

Does anyone have idea? 
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need some dev packages:

```
sudo apt-get install libqt4-dev
```

Edit ./configure, as per this patch:

```
@@ -48,6 +48,11 @@

        fi ;
 done ;
+
+MOC="/usr/bin/moc" ;
+QT_LIB="-L /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ -lqt-mt" ;
+QT_INCLUDE="-I /usr/include/qt"
+
 if [ ! "$QT_INCLUDE" ]; then
        echo -e "\n\n*** Qt 3.x not found please set QT_INCLUDE, QT_LIB, MOC by hand\n\a"
        exit 1
@@ -64,6 +69,8 @@
        fi ;
 done ;

+UIC="/usr/usr/bin/uic";
+
 if [ ! "$UIC" ]; then
        echo -e "\n\n*** uic  not found please set UIC by hand\n\a"
        exit 1
```

That will get you further, but you'll still require an installation of **carmen** somewhere - maybe follow [this guide](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/carmen)?

Extra notes, if you want to find out what package provides files that the configure script is looking for, **apt-file search** is your friend:

```
sudo apt-get install apt-file
apt-file update
apt-file search bin/uic  # for example
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I still meet the same problem after installing all the dependent packages. That's wierd...

Comment: did you also edit the configure file?

Comment: No, I keep it unchanged

Comment: Ok, as per my post - you need to edit the file. Add the lines with a + next to them, in the indicated position in the file